# setOnMapClickListener на kotlin - как отловить нажатия по MapView

Tags: android, kotlin, mapview

Пытаюсь разобраться как отловить нажатия по карте.

На Java делается так:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0){
               //
            }
        });
```

Не понимаю как сделать на Котлин? Сама студия не может сконвертировать код java на котлин (выдает report-ы).

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, OnMapClickListener {
...
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) { 
        mMap = googleMap

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener(
            { p0 -> Log.d("map", p0.toString()) }) ) // в LogCat пусто

        }
}
```

Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось что просто нужно убрать "OnMapClickListener" отсюда:
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, OnMapClickListener

Полностью рабочий код:

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) { 
        mMap = googleMap

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener(
            { p0 -> Log.e("map", p0.toString()) }) ) 

    }
}
```